# Are poster sessions worthless for math grad students?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, cv, presentation, poster

Are poster sessions important in mathematics?
Does being accepted to present a poster at a SIAM conference add something to my CV when I apply to graduate programs or it won't add much?

I am a master's student.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poster sessions, like any academic activity with a reviewed publication will add something to your CV. Not as much as a full paper, but positive.

Poster sessions are, however, also valuable since they give you the opportunity to meet people and some of those people might be the ones to review an application later. Beyond that, it gives you experience in presenting your ideas to people, which has its own merits.

Even the creation of the poster is a valuable experience if it forces you to focus your ideas. The benefits may be individually small, but there are several to consider.

Comment: Amplifying the middle paragraph: keep an eye out for senior members of the community who attend a/the poster session and make an overt effort to engage  the presented research. Senior researchers who are generous with their time, in this way, with younger researchers, are excellent candidates with whom you can try to build further relationships (even if it doesn't click with your own specific poster).